# Can you invoke a method of an object using a string?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
 string stuff = "";
 public doStuff(string stuff)
 {
   this.stuff = stuff;
 }
}

public static Main()
{
string methodName = "doStuff";
List<MyClass> classList = new List<MyClass>();
for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++)
{
classList.Add(new MyClass);
}
foreach(MyClass class in classList)
{
class.Invoke(methodName, new object[]{randomString})
}
}
```

And so every MyClass's stuff has a different value.

Is there a way I can invoke a method this way using reflection?

Comment: Do you mean a method on an object within the same process? Or a different one?

Comment: I cant imagine a possibility of doing this. Because a process is a bit more than a simple class or object you are calling.

Comment: This was just an example with Processes. I could imagine doing this with multiple different objects of a class.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469027/call-methods-using-names-in-c-sharp

Comment: This sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), What problem are you having that using reflection to call methods by name is the solution to that problem?

Comment: The problem is that I need to call methods of different objects. Like in the upper example

Comment: It sounds like you've made a design error somewhere earlier in the process that has put you in this position. While this is certainly possible, the need to do it is a strong signal that you want to go back and rework things to avoid needing this in the first place.

Comment: I'd wager that one or more of inheritance, interfaces, or switch blocks would solve your actual problem (the nature of which remains elusive).

Comment: This thread at codeproject solved my problem : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial

Comment: I didn't know that every object has its own type information. I taugth object share the type info .