# convert string to function: execute a function or event of my code

Tags: c#, string

I am stuck at a point where I wanted a string to execute a function or event of my code. For example if

```
string somestr = "fun";
```

I want to execute a function called fun

```
public bool fun()
{
    return true;
}
```

I can manipulate `somestr` to like "execute fun" or "fun()" or something.

I best I could have thought till now is create a event or function where I should check and compare the string in switch case and execute the function or raise the event like

```
public void ReceivedCommand()
{
    if(somestr == "fun")
    {
        bool b = fun();
    }
    else if(somestr == "Otherfun")
    {
        //Some Other Function
    }
}
```

But now the case is that I have few hundreds of function and few events and user can choose any of them. I am very sure that there should be something that can solve my thing in a easy way instead writing lot of ifs and switch.

Could you please point me to the right direction how should I be able to do this.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469027/call-methods-using-names-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get the method that you want with it's name using Type.GetMethod(methodName).
see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Something like [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469027/call-methods-using-names-in-c-sharp) right?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

You could do it dynamically like this

```
class MethodInvoker
{
    delegate void TestDelegate();

    public void fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fun");
    }

    public void InvokeFromString(string functionName)
    {
        TestDelegate tDel = () => { this.GetType().GetMethod(functionName).Invoke(this, null); };
        tDel.Invoke();
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
var test = new MethodInvoker();
test.InvokeFromString("fun");
```

Comment: Lemme try this. I am sure it is going to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection. Something like this:

```
Type type = this.GetType();
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(somestr);
methodInfo.Invoke(this, userParameters);

// And this requires "using System.Reflection;"
```

or

Try [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19911/dynamically-invoke-a-method-given-strings-with-met) link, i hope it works

Comment: Are you sure? Lemme give it a try. But it seems its is not going to work.

Comment: It works, check this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/calling-javascript-function-from-string/

Comment: It's not a Javascript question. Look at the tags.

Comment: y, i saw : Use this link - https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19911/dynamically-invoke-a-method-given-strings-with-met